# How can I add and use image in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

I have found many solutions, but for old versions and other platforms, that don't work.
Am using Xaramin Forms to have cross-platform usage.

- Do I need a specific schema?
- Should I put my image into a folder (to be neat)?  If so, how reference it?

Currently: portable project has all pictures in a folder called "Images".  (eg. 'logo.png').

tried:

> XAML: **<Image x:Name="imgLogo" Source="/Images/logo.png">** - Not
>   displayed

> C#: **imgLogo.Source = "/Images/logo.png";** - Not displayed either

Since it is only for appearance, not dynamic, XAML should be fine.

Also I'd like have the image clickable. So how should I wrap in a button?

#### PART 2: ANOTHER (FUTURE) STEP

What is the simplest way to have a few sliding images?
I have a string array of filenames...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have Images within your PCL project, they need to be Embedded resources but you need to jump through some hoops to call them via XAML. Take a look at the [Embedded Images section](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/#embedded_images) of the Images article on official Xamarin documentation.

1. You need an IMarkupExtension that finds the image resource specified in XAML.
2. You can then call images like this: `<Image Source="{local:ImageResource WorkingWithImages.beach.jpg}" />`

Regarding the sliding images, take a look at the [CarouselView](https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/) control that let's you swipe through (for example) a list of images.

Comment: Good answer! I simply needed to mark the image as an 'Embedded Resource' and use the dot-notation. I tried to increase your score, but my reputation is too low.

Comment: However that Carousel didn't work for me ..not all classes, etc. explained in their post. Even their Git solution download failed to compile...

Also I want to make the image clickable, do you know the CORRECT way to do that? (I keep getting error: Can not set the content of Button as it doesn't have a ContentPropertyAttribute)

Comment: @user3247130 You could also try this CarouselView library: https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView It gets updated more of then than the first one I linked to and has a demo in the repository. Regarding a clickable image, here's a tutorial in the official documentation on how to do just that: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/tap/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using absolute path.

Change to relative path.

ex :

```
<Image x:Name="imgLogo" Source="../Images/logo.png">
```

You can display image to your SW.